# How to fix file system problems in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04, vps

I want to ask when I move the Laravel project to VPS an error like this appears.

https://i.postimg.cc/mr4bB9WX/Screenshot-18.jpg

What I have done is:

```html
$ sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
$ sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
$ chmod -R 775 storage
$ chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
# composer update
```

Comment: This is permission problem to your theme/gallery folder.

Comment: how to fix this on ubuntu 16 ?

Comment: You may do it like so. sudo chmod -R 777 theme/gallery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to your project folder and open terminal.
run this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 theme/gallery
```

Comment: but i checked with ftp file can't save on theme/gallery ? @shankar-s-bavan

Comment: Is it saved on localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like like so.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 theme/gallery
```